# if string contains brackets, check content of brackets

Tags: regex

I want to check the content of brackets in a string, e.g. `[foo]_bla_[bar]`. The content of brackets which should be accepted is limited to let's say `foo` and `bar`.

So for instance `[foo]_bla_[bar]` and `[foo]_argh_[bar]` would be accepted, whereas `[foo]_bla_[lol]` or `[fooL]_bla_[lol]` would not. 
On the other hand, if no bracket is present, the string should be match.

Any hints how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @sp00m: I spend quite some time with conditions (http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

Comment: Could you provide those tries? Which regexes did not work?

Comment: @sp00m It nothing usefull yet.. just playing around. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\[(?:foo|bar)\][^\[]*\[(?:foo|bar)\]$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/10

Comment: looks pretty much like what I was looking for.